# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow_core.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing' has no attribute 'RandomFlip'

Tags: tensorflow2.x

I use Tensorflow 2.1.0
In this code

```
data_augmentation = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.RandomFlip('horizontal'),
    tf.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.RandomRotation(0.3)
])
```

I find this error:

```
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow_core.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing' has no attribute 'RandomFlip'
```

So how can I change it without changing version of tensorflow

Answer (score 10):

To work your code as expected, firstly Tensorflow has to be upgrade to the latest version

```
! pip install tensorflow --upgrade
```

If you are looking for solution in TF 2.1.0, then there are two options are available

First solution:  [tf.image.random_flip_left_right](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.1/api_docs/python/tf/image/random_flip_left_right) ( horizontal flip)

```
tf.image.random_flip_left_right(
    image, seed=None)
```

Second solution: [tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.1/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/ImageDataGenerator)

```
tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(
   rotation_range=30, horizontal_flip=True)
```

Comment: Updating your TensorFlow with pip command is always the first thing you should try. Worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

```
! pip install tensorflow --upgrade --user
```

`--user` option can help you without the ***permission*** problem

Answer (score 1):

Add this line to the importing section (of course after `import tensorflow as tf`)
`tf.config.experimental_run_functions_eagerly(True)`

Almost any `tf.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.SomeClass` in the listed classes [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/experimental/preprocessing), should work.

But need to do sanity check with plotting results.